# Filter what one group sees vs another group

Tags: 2010, infopath

This is a 2 part question because I need to get one part working first then the other.  Sorry, I am a newbie as well.  I am building a site where a form is submitted and another group can add notes and keep tabs on it.  I created the form with all the fields so my question is.  With this Form, how do I have it to where the user can only see certain fields and the other users see the complete form with all the notes.  How do I filter it on the user side.  Second part of that is how do I link the users account to that form (sorta like the "modify" and "created" things do.

Answer (score 0):

Forms are going to be attached to content types, and unfortunately in 2010 at least there is not a way to restrict access on content types. One thing you can do instead is create custom actions for the forms and then restrict viewership of those custom actions to the groups you want to be able to see them. Doing so, of course, will force you to hook up the wires on the forms themselves and the users won't have access to the standard GUI with the "Copy" and "Check Spelling" buttons at the top, but this is how we've run one of our solutions where I am.